# Unhandled exception (ucrtbase.dll): An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm using VS2015 and OpenCV 2.4.13 over Windows 10.
I have a code that extracts certain features from images.
The code crashes in the middle of going through a set defined as follow:

```
std::set<cv::Scalar, Structless> colors;
```

In the call stack, I get:

```
FeaturesExtractionLib.dll!std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > ::deallocate(cv::Point_<int> * _Ptr, unsigned __int64 _Count) Line 987  C++
```

The code is as follow:

```
std::set<Scalar>::iterator it = colors.begin();
while (it != colors.end())
{
    Mat mask = Mat::zeros(Size(data.cols, data.rows), CV_8UC1);
    /* fill the mask according to some reasoning... */
    bitwise_and(mask, maskOrig, mask); // result is a mask of my ROI 
    vector <vector<Point>> contours;
    tRegion reg; // tRegion is a structure defining a collection of ROI sharing some commun parameters 

    // dot and region
    findContours(mask, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        double a = abs(contourArea(contours[i]));
        CvRect box = boundingRect(contours[i]);
        if ((box.x > 1) && (box.y > 1) && (box.x + box.width < aligned->width - 1) && (box.y + box.height < aligned->height - 1))
        {
            if (n_region < MAX_N_REGION)
            {
                vector<Point> contourTemp;
                for (int j = 0; j < contours[i].size(); j++)
                {
                    contourTemp.push_back(Point(contours[i][j].x + roi.x, contours[i][j].y + roi.y));
                }
                reg.contours.push_back(contourTemp);
            }
        }
    }
    regions.push_back(reg);
    it++;
}
```

It seems that the exception because of the std::set. 
It is worth mentioning that the code used to work fine in another project. The only difference between the two projects is the fact that this one build for as a library (to finally generate a dll file)

Comment: Is the code badly arranged? The while loop is an endless loop as `it` only gets incremented afterwards. The bottom two lines should probably be within the loop.

Comment: It's crashing trying to deallocate `contours`.  As the storage used by it was allocated by another function do all the runtime library options match?

Comment: @nucleon, they are in the loop. it's just a typo. I edited it to fix it.

Comment: @RichardCritten the runtime libraries match. And before you ask, I tried all options and I noticed that for /MT the code crashes even before this loop, exactly at the first call of "findContours" of OpenCV.